# Lua set timeout for connect

Tags: lua

Looks like [setting timeout](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#settimeout) for Lua socket only works after `connect`, and I can't use `assert (socket.connect (..))`, because I have multiple servers to try out.

My scenario is that when one server is down (can't connect rather than unstable network), I will resort to a different one, so I must have a timeout on connect.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I found Lua TCP socket, but with that, I was unable to detect connection failure,

```
local tcp = socket.tcp()
tcp:settimeout(1)
tcp:connect(...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it does not work it is probably because your luasocket is too old, update to version 2:

> Starting with LuaSocket 2.0, the settimeout method affects the behavior of connect, causing it to return with an error in case of a timeout.
>
> (source: http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#connect)

Comment: But prior to socket.connect, the object is nil, no way to call the settimeout(), am I wrong?

Comment: No, you need to use the two step method from your edit (create the TCP socket, then set the timeout, then connect).